# Exist an algorithm to calculate the rank of a bit matrix without branching?

Tags: algorithm, matrix, ranking

The bit matrix is over the GF(2) field, and whether an algorithm calculating the rank of a matrix without branches(`if`,`for`,`while`) exists?

I plan to use GPGPU to accelerate the calculation, since bit matrices are small (the number of rows or columns is less than 100), but they are numerous.

Comment: You probably mean "branching", not "branch prediction"?

Comment: What's the typical size of your matrix? And is it square?

Comment: matrices tested are small (rows <100, columns< 50), but I have a enormously huge number of them.

Answer (score 0):

There probably is no way to do this without using `if`, `for` etc.

Since you have many matrices of small sizes you might want to parallelize the computation like map reduce. Eg. You have 100 matrices give 10 of them to 10 different machines.

Since you have many matrices not large matrices, I think map reduce will be right way to parallelize the problem instead of GPU.

Read more on [map reduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce).